# Firefox Marionette is detected by hCaptcha

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

Whenever I visit indeed.com using firefox web driver in Marionette mode. I get hit with an hCaptcha prompt. I tried using a user script that runs at document-start to overwrite the `navigator.webdriver` getter and set it to return false. I also checked if any additional headers were being sent or if the user agent was changed in the networking tab, but neither were. How can I avoid having firefox Marionette detected?

Comment: Rather than constantly fighting this, have you considered their [developer API](https://developer.indeed.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not indeed.com, it is just cloudflare protection guard. And the reason cloudflare shows captcha is IP reputation. Your flow may not be realistic from this IP. I see no difference in marionette mode and without it for indeed.com.